# Linker error LNK2005 founded in visual studio 2022 but not in g++

Tags: c++, visual-studio, g++

I have an assignment in my university and I'm provided 3 files below

main.cpp:

```
#include "main.h"
#include "Restaurant.cpp"
#include <fstream>
...
...
```

main.h

```
#ifndef RESTAURANT_H
#define RESTAURANT_H
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <math.h>

using namespace std;

int MAXSIZE;
...
...
```

Restaurant.cpp

```
#include "main.h"
...
```

And here is the error I received:

```
Build started...
1>------ Build started: Project: Assignment_01, Configuration: Debug x64 ------
1>Restaurant.cpp
1>main.cpp
1>Generating Code...
1>LINK : D:\Study_DSA\Assignment_01\VS_Version\Assignment_01\x64\Debug\Assignment_01.exe not found or not built by the last incremental link; performing full link
1>Restaurant.obj : error LNK2005: "int MAXSIZE" (?MAXSIZE@@3HA) already defined in main.obj
1>D:\Study_DSA\Assignment_01\VS_Version\Assignment_01\x64\Debug\Assignment_01.exe : fatal error LNK1169: one or more multiply defined symbols found
1>Done building project "Assignment_01.vcxproj" -- FAILED.
========== Build: 0 succeeded, 1 failed, 0 up-to-date, 0 skipped ==========
========== Build started at 4:04 PM and took 01.193 seconds ==========
```

I've tested and this linker error appeared in both Visual Studio 2022 and CLion IDE (CLion results in different error output but basically the same linker error). But when I compile and build it using g++ (from MingW), it can build normally. It seems strange because I have header guards in main.h to prevent redefinition (I don't know why its name is  RESTAURANT_H, it should be MAIN_H but that is the default code).

So what should I do if I want to continue to code in VStudio (or basically any IDE). In this assignment, I can only change Restaurant.cpp file because that is the requirement of the assignment.

Also I want to understand clearly why g++ can build it and why VStudio can't, because it seems strange to me, the MAXSIZE can't be redeclared in this case.

I will appreciate any help, thank you so much.

Comment: *What should I do...?* **Never** include one cpp file in another.

Comment: Any reasonable source for C++ is going to explain how to organise your code into source files and header files. You seem to be making multiple mistakes in this area. I suggest you do some studying.

Comment: Would mind explaining it clearly why and how this creates an error? and why g++ not? Yeah I can do as you said if I had full access to all files in my assignment, sorry if I don't get your idea.

Comment: Do not put normal variable definitions like `int MAXSIZE;` in header files.

Comment: If your teacher/tutor/professor or whoever gave you files where .cpp files are included into other .cpp files (like in `#include "Restaurant.cpp"`), then you should seriously question their qualification for teaching C++.

Comment: Perhaps when you compile with g++ you're only compiling `main.cpp` and `restaurant.cpp` is compiled via inclusion. In Visual Studio you have `restaurant.cpp` in your project so it is compiled twice leading to multiple definitions. Either do the right thing, remove the inclusion of the cpp file, and compile it correctly with both compilers or exclude `restaurant.cpp` from the build in Visual Studio.

Comment: @NguyễnThànhDanh It's because you compiled the file `Restaurant.cpp` twice, once by itself and once when it's included in `main.cpp`. So you get a multiple definition error. I guess when you compiled with g++ you only compiled `main.cpp` so `Restaurant.cpp` also only got compiled once. The bottom line is the cpp files are compiled directly and header files are included, that's the difference between the two.

Answer (score 1):

Besides that `Restaurant.cpp` shouldn't be #included in another cpp file (as already mentioned in the comments), the line

```cpp
int MAXSIZE;
```

creates a variable in each compilation unit where the file `main.h` is included (which could be many, if you have a large project). Change this to

```cpp
extern int MAXSIZE;
```

and then add the `int MAXSIZE;` to `Main.cpp`. That way the definition exists only once.

Comment: And rename `Restaurant.cpp` to `Restaurant.h` so you don't confuse everybody.

Comment: @john I'd rather say make sure we have both. `Restaurant.cpp` probably contains implementation, so the corresponding .h file is missing.

Comment: It seems that your solution doesn't work well. But based on the idea that VStudio automatically build all files (two friendly people in the comments). I've switched to CMake and only build the main.cpp so it worked for me. Anyway I will note all the comments and will try my best to prevent bad practice like this.